# Help with DIV layout and CSS height

Tags: css, height, html

Please see the screenshot. I am trying to produce a layout that allows me to apply shadow to either side of the main div using the divs left (headerLeft) and right(headerRight), I then have the content div(header) that holds the header content. This is all wrapped in a div (headerWrapper). I am using 4 divs to do this. I have it working on my header, nav bar and another bar I am using. This is shown with the colour coded divs on the screenshot. The reason this works is because my CSS is using heights given in pixels. However I have problem. I want to apply this to my main content, but it won't work. The content is going to change in height from page to page this is fine, however my divs that contain the shadows don't appear, unless I give them a fixed pixel height. Please help.The red areas show where the left and right divs containing the shadows should appear.

[layoutProblem http://www.webquark.co.uk/layoutProblem.jpg](http://www.webquark.co.uk/layoutProblem.jpg)

Here is the CSS I have for the layouts that work:

```
    #header{
margin:0 auto; 
height:160px;
width: 76%;
min-width:850px;
font-size: 14pt;
font-family: Calibri, Verdana, Ariel, sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
background-image: url(headerBG.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x; 
}

#headerWrapper{
height:145px;
width:100%;
/**background-color: #202020;**/
}

#headerLeft
{
float: left;
width: 12%;
height:145px;
background-image: url(shadowLeft.png);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: center right;
/**background-color: #1e1e1e;**/
}

#headerRight
{
float: right;
width: 12%;
height:145px;
background-image: url(shadowRight.png);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: center left;
/**background-color: #1e1e1e;**/
}
```

Basicly I think I need away of making the left and right divs height 100%, I have tried setting the height to 100% but it doesnt work. I also have my body height set to 100%

Cheers, hope you can help.

HTML for the working top bar and Header:

```
<div id="topWrapper">
<div id="topRight">
</div>
<div id="topLeft">
</div>
<div id="top">
</div>
</div>


 <div id="headerWrapper">
 <div id="headerRight">
</div>
<div id="headerLeft">
</div>
 <div id="header">
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you post your html as well, please? Or link to your demo-page/page-in-progress? I can sort of see what the CSS is doing, but it's difficult to be sure without seeing to what it's attached. Cheers =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a transparent PNG for the shadow, 1px high. It would contain the shadow on the left, then a blank area the width of the content/header, then the right hand shadow. In the example below this would be 1x932 pixels.

Example code:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #headerBG {
    background: gray url("repeating-background");
  }
  #contentBG {
    background: red url("repeating-background");
  }
  .shadow {
    width: 900px; /* width of inner content */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 16px; /* width of shadow bit */
    background: transparent url("new-shadow") repeat-y;
  }
</style>

<div id="headerBG">
  <div class="shadow">
    header content
  </div>
  <div class="shadow">
    navigation
  </div>
</div>

<div id="contentBG">
  <div class="shadow">
    body content
  </div>
</div>
```

For the different background colours on the header/body, you'll either need to add an extra div inside the shadow (around the content), or create multiple shadow images where the blank bit in the middle contains the correct background color. However if you're filling the header with a separate image anyway you could probably get away with just the body color - the header will cover that up.

Comment: Cheers, works based on what you said. Changed a few things though.

Answer (score 0):

Getting divs to match heights is very hard to do with CSS. There are some tricks to doing it, but I think there's an easier solution here.

Why not just make the red pattern the body background image and have it tile? If you want to display something else, just have it go on top. From what I can see of your design, that looks like the easiest solution to me.

If you do want to try to get the divs to match heights, I'd suggest using the [absolute columns trick](http://24ways.org/2008/absolute-columns). Something like this will work, I think: (Although I haven't actually tested it.)

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left-shadow"></div>
    <div id="text">
        text goes here
    </div>
    <div id="right-shadow"></div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
}
    #left-shadow {
        position: relative;
        left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
        /* width needs to be specified */
    }
    #text {
        /* width needs to be specified */
    }
    #right-shadow {
        position: relative;
        right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
        /* width needs to be specified */
    }
```

And then set the pattern as the background images for left/right-shadow.